# Why ajax couldn't reload new post?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How do I make autoload/reload in every 5 seconds in ajax?

This is the code I use. The problem is new data doesn't appear, unless I reload it.

```php
$(document).ready(function(){
    // temp
        $.ajax({
            url : 'assets/php/act_now/module_loadChat.php',
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            success: function(show_chat) {
                $('#direct-chat').html(show_chat);
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
    // temp

    $("#text-on-it").submit(function(event){ // when send message
        event.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'assets/php/act_now/module_loadChat.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#direct-chat').html(data);
                $("#text-on-it")[0].reset();
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code, but post the code itself.

Comment: well hope your server can handle the load. Use setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function(){
    // this will run after every 5 seconds
}, 5000);
```